# I'm having issues w/ my RNN; keeps predicting too high numbers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

So I'm creating a frame AI network to predict substantial outbreaks throughout the world. The first step of my process is predicting factor data over the next couple of years. So far, I've been calling a function to make my models and saving them as different files. I've stored my data in the same file to make it easier. Here is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as kr
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
import math
def AIcooker(name_of_the_pdf, number_of_epochs, vertical_length_of_set, horizontal_length_of_set, splitting_percentage, window_size, time_horizon, i_var):
    water = pd.read_csv(
    name_of_the_pdf,
    parse_dates = True,
    index_col = 'Date'
    )
    water = water.drop('Date.1', axis = 1)
    warray = water.values

    water.replace([np.inf, -np.inf, np.nan], 0, inplace=True)
    
    nom = math.floor(vertical_length_of_set*splitting_percentage)

    train = water.iloc[:nom]
    test = water.iloc[nom:]
    
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    scaler.fit(train)
    scaler_train = scaler.transform(train)
    scaler_test = scaler.transform(test)
    
    n_input = window_size
    n_features = horizontal_length_of_set
    generator = TimeseriesGenerator(scaler_train, scaler_train, length = n_input, batch_size = 1)
    
    X, y = generator[0]
    X.shape
    
    model = kr.Sequential()
    model.add(kr.layers.Reshape((n_input, n_features)))
    model.add(LSTM(512, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (n_input, n_features)))
    model.add(Dense(512))
    model.add(Dense(512))
    model.add(Dense(512))
    model.add(Dense(n_features))
    model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mse')
    
    i = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
        monitor=i_var,
        patience=20,
        restore_best_weights=True,
        verbose = 1
    )
    model.fit(generator, epochs = number_of_epochs, callbacks = [i])
    
    last_trained_batch = scaler_train[-n_input:]
    last_trained_batch = last_trained_batch.reshape((1, n_input, n_features))
    c = model.predict(last_trained_batch)
    
    test_predictions = []
    first_eval_batch = scaler_train[-n_input:]
    current_batch = first_eval_batch.reshape((1, n_input, n_features))
    
    for i in range(time_horizon):  # Iterate for the specified time horizon
        current_pred = model.predict(current_batch)[0]
        test_predictions.append(current_pred)
        current_batch = np.append(current_batch[:, 1:, :], [[current_pred]], axis=1)

    
    ui = scaler.inverse_transform(test_predictions)
    print(ui)

    return model, ui
""" model1, ui1 = AIcooker('HI - HI.csv', 10000, 23, 130, 0.9, 8, 100, 'loss')
model1.save('WaterQuality.keras')
np.savetxt('WaterQualityResults.txt', ui1, fmt='%.18f')
model2, ui2 = AIcooker('yy.csv', 10000, 30, 192, 0.8, 7, 100, 'loss')
model2.save('PD.keras')
np.savetxt('PDResults.txt', ui2, fmt='%.18f') 
model3, ui3 = AIcooker('34.csv', 3000, 22, 192, 0.8, 7, 100, 'loss')
model3.save('P.keras')
np.savetxt('PResults.txt', ui3, fmt='%.18f')"""
'''model4, ui4 = AIcooker('0-4.csv', 5000, 71, 236, 0.8, 7, 100, 'val_loss')
model4.save('0-4.keras')
np.savetxt('0-4Results.txt', ui4, fmt='%.18f')'''
model5, ui5 = AIcooker('6.csv', 5000, 7, 126, 0.8, 7, 100, 'loss')
model5.save('0-0.keras')
np.savetxt('0-0Results.txt', ui5, fmt='%.18f')
```

So, uh, yeah.

Now, my issue.

It may be commented out, but model4 is meant to predict infant/toddler populations across the world. 0-4.csv has over 100 nations of the worlds' estimated toddler/children population from 1950 to 2022. The issue is, as I'm extending it, it gets alarmingly innacurate (like, -98 hendecillion innacurate). I've tried overfitting it to an immense degree and trying to run it for hours (hence the undefined 'val_loss' metric so that it turns off the EarlyCallback), but no.It will not work. Although with all other data, it works fine. I'm not going to post the csv unless needed 'cause, like, it's huge.

Thank you so much to anybody that helps.

Comment: why are the imports in the function ? did you mean that ?

Comment: No. If you see, it also extends the given amount of data by a couple of years. Theextension is churning out impossible data, been if I extremely overfit it.

Comment: Do you have big outliers in your data? `MinMaxScaler` is prone to that, in that case it squeezes all other data into a tiny range to fit the outliers in [0, 1]. You could also try out a batch size larger than 1, it could be that the model does not generealize well with only one example per batch. You can also look out for trends in your data.

Comment: @mhenning Thank you so, so much. I tried changing it to ''' MinMaxScaler(0,100) ''' and it now works! Again, thanks!

Comment: Although I'm glad it works better now, `MinMaxScaler(0, 100)` is generally not the right approach! Take a look at [StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) or [RobustScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.RobustScaler.html), both handle outlier more flexible. Also take a look at the distribution of your input data to choose a scaling method.